# Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

Guys I also face same issue like message could not be sent mailer Error, I searched on google and try all method but still getting an same issue
please help me to solve my error

method 1 :

> i allow to less secure app

method 2 :

> I enter properly email and password

```
<?php 

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; 

require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 

try { 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                    
    $mail->isSMTP();                                             
    $mail->Host  = 'smtp.gmail.com;';                    
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          
    $mail->Username = '****@gmail.com';              
    $mail->Password = '*******';                         
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                           
    $mail->Port  = 587; 

    $mail->setFrom('*************', 'Name');         
    $mail->addAddress('*****************'); 
    $mail->addAddress('***********', 'Name'); 
    
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
    $mail->Subject = 'Subject'; 
    $mail->Body = 'HTML message body in <b>bold</b> '; 
    $mail->AltBody = 'Body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients'; 
    $mail->send(); 
    echo "Mail has been sent successfully!"; 
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}"; 
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you have an authentication issue with Gmail. Please make sure you have completed the following steps prior to connecting to Gmail.

```
# Visit https://accounts.google.com
#
# 1. Click on [Security] menu
# 2. Scroll to section [Less secure app access] and set it to ON
# 3. Scroll to section [Signing in to Google] and set [Use your phone to sign in] to OFF 
# 4. Scroll to section [Signing in to Google] and set [2-step Verification] to OFF 
#
```

Comment: i  tried all method that you mentioned but its not working